# WCF web service not working after deployed

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am trying to create a WCF web service which will allow other applications to retrieve a string by making a http request to this service url. I tried publishing the service in IIS and when attempting to browse  to it, using the url, it says it

```
' The resource cannot be found'
```

when I checked the path to the folder I used the url, 
and I get the error

```
'No protocol binding matches the given address 
'http://localhost:xxxx/WcfSampleLibrary/Service1/mex.' 
 Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS configuration'
```

Here is the directory  path of the published folder:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WcfServices\WcfSampleLibrary\WcfSampleLibrary.Service1
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WcfServices\WcfSampleLibrary\Web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WcfServices\WcfSampleLibrary\bin\WcfSampleLibrary.dll
```

The web config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfSampleLibrary.Service1" behaviorConfiguration ="mex">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http://192.xxx.x.xxx/WcfSampleLibrary/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address ="" 
      binding="wsHttpBinding"  contract="WcfSampleLibrary.IService1">
     <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:xxxx/WcfSampleLibrary/Service1/mex" name="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mex">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: You published it to IIS on the same machine and setup to listen on the port `xxxx`?

Comment: Your `baseAddress` is different from your service endpoint `address`. usually you can omit `baseAddress`altogether.

Comment: I did not set the port but wanted to just use the server ip address; it set the port itself

Comment: If I remove the baseAddress can I change the endpoint address to use the ip in it so it can be accessed from within the LAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IIS-hosted WCF services you don't specify a full URI in the address. IIS decides the address. Also the `baseAddresses` element is completely ignored when hosting in IIS (so remove it from you Web.config). The service's base address is determined by the web site & virtual directory into which your wcf service is placed.Do something like this:

```
  <endpoint
    address="mex"
    binding="mexHttpBinding"
    contract="IMetadataExchange"
  />
```

Then your address would be http://IIS.SERVER/SiteName/Folder/WcfSampleLibrary.Service1.svc. If you're not sure what the address is, use your IIS Administration tool, select the site that has the service in it, Right-click and choose Advanced -> Browse Site.

Also, I'd turn on httpGetEnabled on your `mex` behavior--if you want to publish your WSDL. This makes it easier to consume your service as you are developing it:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mex" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

With `httpGetEnabled` being on, browsing to your service URI will give you an option to see the WSDL.

Comment: thank you for your explanation...I tried the changes and now I get the error: the web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory..when using browse site in IIS. When I type the whole url in the browser manually, it returns the resouce cannot be found...is this just a security/sharing issue. Also

Comment: IT may not list the contents of the directory (you can turn it on in IIS administrator), but at least you get the URI that your web server is using to host it. What files are in the web folder? Do you have a `ServiceName.svc` file?

Comment: The service file is not in the web folder; I have the WcfSampleLibrary.dll in the bin folder and web.config file in the main folder. Should I add the service file manually?

Comment: Yes. Also make sure the .svc file is referencing a .DLL that is in your bin/ folder. So the first line of your .svc file has: `<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="Namespace.And.Name.Of.Assembly"%>` The value of Service should be referencing your assembly in the bin folder.